# What is partial integration when we are integrating with respect to a CDF?

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, expected-value

What is the rule for partial integration when we are integrating with respect to a CDF $F$ of a random variable?

For example, see this excerpt from a book:

[image]

What is going on in the second equality? In particular I don't understand how we go from $dF(x)$ to $dx$. That doesn't seem to be integration by parts, that's something that usually happens when we do substitution, no?

Comment: The $dF(x)$ usually refers to a Riemann-Stieltjes integral. Maybe you could elaborate the context. What is it you are calculating? What is the underlying distribution?

Comment: In particular if there is a pdf $f$, then $\int ... dF(x)=\int...f(x)\,dx$, the usual Riemann integral.

Comment: I think the image contains all the information. $F$ is just a generic distribution, and we are trying to calculate $\int_u^\infty \ln x - \ln u dF(x)$. I don't know what a Riemann-Stieltjes integral is, but I do know, as you say, that $\int ... dF(x) = \int ...f(x)dx$ when $F$ is absolutely continuous .... but that is not (necessarily) the case here.

Comment: The Riemann-Stieltjes integral is a generalization of the classical Riemann integral, a sort of intermediate step before Lebesgue integration. It's like the classical Riemann integral except the intervals (for partitions) are measured using $F$. You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral).

Comment: @Janus Do you need further explanations?

Answer (score 2):

$$
\int\limits_u^\infty (\ln x - \ln u) \, dF(x) = -\int\limits_u^\infty (\ln x - \ln u) \, d(1-F(x))
$$
(integration by parts)
$$
= -\biggl[(\ln x - \ln u) \, (1-F(x))\biggr]_u^\infty +\int\limits_u^\infty (1-F(x)) \, d(\ln x - \ln u) = \int\limits_u^\infty \frac{\overline F(x)}{x} \, dx,
$$
if $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\ln x\cdot\overline F(x)=0$. This is fulfilled for the case under consideration: $\overline F(x)=\frac{L(x)}{x^{\alpha}}$ where $L(x)$ is some slowly varying function.

Other variant is to change order of integration:
$$
\int\limits_u^\infty (\ln x - \ln u) \, dF(x) = \int\limits_u^\infty \,\left(\,\int\limits_u^x \frac1t\,dt \right)\, dF(x) 
$$
$\{x\in(u,\infty), u<t<x\}=\{t\in(u,\infty), x\in(t,\infty)\}$
$$
=\int\limits_u^\infty \frac1t\, \underbrace{\left(\,\int\limits_t^\infty \, dF(x)\right)}_{\overline F(t)} \,dt.
$$
It is always possible to swap integrals of nonnegative functions.